# Display random number in a textbox field in the same HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have code where I need to get a random number when I click the submit button. The random number should be displayed in the same page in another text box.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomnumber(num1, num2)
{
    num1 = parseInt(num1);
    num2 = parseInt(num2);
    if(num1 >= num2)
    {
        alert("Number 2 should be greater than Number 1");
    }
    else
    {
        var generator = Math.random()*(num2-num1);
        generator = Math.round(num1+generator);

        document.test.result.value = generator;
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=generator;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="test" onsubmit = "return randomnumber(num1,num2)" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="num1" size ="35" maxlength= "25">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="num2" size ="35" maxlength= "25">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="p1" value = "" size ="35" maxlength= "25">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value"generate">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The random number is generated in the variable 'generator' in the script. I need to get the value in this textfield.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="p1" value = "" size ="35" maxlength= "25">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
var generator = Math.random()*(num2-num1);
generator = Math.round(num1+generator);

// document.test.result.value = generator; // Not sure what this line is for (don't see a test.result element.
document.getElementById("p1").value=generator;
```

Note `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: the name of the text box is "p1" and not the id

Answer (score 1):

Is better in your html to change your input text in this mode:

```
<input type="text" name="p1" id="p1" value = "" size ="35" maxlength= "25">
```

and use this javascript code to change value:

```
document.getElementById("p1").value=generator;
```

Because the id is unique and you can select better your element

Comment: the name of the text box is "p1" and not the id

Comment: i am getting NaN in the text field

Comment: you have to retrieve data form num1 and num2 int the same mode, put id instead of name into your input and take data in this mode: num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value, and don't put inside a form isn't necessary, is better to insert a button and insert into it event onClick, try this way is better

Comment: sorry wrong link, please refer to this one for [document.getElementsByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536438(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
document.getElementsByName('p1')[0].value = generator
```

The issue is "p1" is not the id of the textbox but the name. The above code will only work for  the case of one element with the name "p1".

The following will work only if you use "p1" as the Id of your textbox.

```
document.getElementById('p1').value = generator
```

Also, for textboxes, use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code (as well as the intended functionality, which looks like a homework assignment). To put text in the input field, it is best to use an `id` attribute in the element, `id="p1"` in this case, and assign to `document.getElementById('p1').value`. Do not use form submission, since you are not submitting data to a server-side form handler. Instead, use `<input type="button">` and an `onclick` event handler in it. Check the input values for being numeric, at least by testing the result of `parseInt()`, before doing any comparisons on them. Remove the assignment to `document.test.result.value`, as its an erroneous reference and aborts the execution of the rest of the code. And check your HTML markup with a markup validator.

Answer (score 0):

what is result

document.test.result.value=generator;

try name of the field p1.

document.test.p1.value=generator;